# Can someone pleae help me with new powershell password exp script?

Tags: powershell

```
$dates = 30, 10, 3, 2, 1 | ForEach-Object {
(Get-Date).Date.AddDays( - $_)
}
Get-ADUser -Filter { Enabled -eq $true} -Properties Description, 'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed' |
Select-Object SamAccountName, UserPrincipalName, Description,
@{n='PasswordExpires';e={
    [DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed')
}}|
    Where-Object { $_.PasswordExpires.Date -in $dates } |
    ForEach-Object { 
    $daysToExpiry = [Math]::Floor(($_.PasswordExpires - (Get-Date)).TotalDays)

    $mailParams = @{
        To         = $_.UserPrincipalName
        From       = 'blah@blah.com
        Body       = "Your password will expire in $daysToExpiry"
        Subject    = "Password expires in $daysToExpiry"
        SmtpServer = 'blah.smtp.com'
    }
    Send-MailMessage @params
    $_
} | Export-Csv output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Anyone see anything standing out?  I ran this across my test domain with users setup to expire in 30 days and they do not receive anything.  The csv is also blank.

Comment: Your `$dates` variable is in the past. Remove the minus sign from line 2, and see if that helps.

Comment: There is a missing `'` in line: `From       = 'blah@blah.com`

Comment: Oh, and you are probably never going to get it to work like that. Now that I think about it you are trying to compare dates, which includes the time of day not just the date. So unless their password is going to expire in exactly 30 days, down to the second (millisecond?) from the time the script is run, this won't produce results.

Comment: I have tested your script as well with 3 accounts both expiring in 30 days ( I changed the default domain policy) and the same thing occurs as my script above.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, comparing dates like you are probably isn't going to work very well. What I would suggest is to calculate the days until expiration, and add that as a property. Then you can see if that number is in an array of things to see if their password expires in X number of days.

```
$dates = 30, 10, 3, 2, 1
Get-ADUser -Filter { Enabled -eq $true} -Properties Description, 'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed' |
Select-Object SamAccountName, UserPrincipalName, Description,
@{n='PasswordExpires';e={
    [DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed')
}},
@{n='DaysToExpiry';e={[Math]::Floor(([DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed') - [datetime]::Now).TotalDays)}}|
    Where-Object { $_.DaysToExpiry -in $dates } |
    ForEach-Object { 
    $daysToExpiry = $_.DaysToExpiry

    $mailParams = @{
        To         = $_.UserPrincipalName
        From       = 'blah@blah.com'
        Body       = "Your password will expire in $daysToExpiry"
        Subject    = "Password expires in $daysToExpiry"
        SmtpServer = 'blah.smtp.com'
    }
    Send-MailMessage @params
    $_
} | Export-Csv output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

**Break Down:**

First I've changed the `$dates` variable to an array of numbers. Specifically the number of days in the future that you want to notify people on. Then I added a second calculated property called 'DaysToExpiry' to each object that calculates the number of days until their password expires (which you were doing later in the script). Then I evaluate if their password till expire in one of the days defined in the `$dates` variable. Inside of the `ForEach-Object` loop I define `$daysToExpiry` based off of the property that I defined earlier since there's no need to do that calculation twice. That's all of the changes that I made to the script.

**Edit:** I just realized today that I was incorrect in my original statement about running into issues with specific times not aligning. The `.Date` property gives you a `[DateTime]` object with only the day, month, and year retained, and everything else set to zero, so you will not run into time specific issues. Now, that said, my answer still works fine, and even with my new found knowledge I would still take this approach if it were me, but in all fairness I felt I should edit my answer to include this information. In the end you could have probably just removed the minus sign from line 2 of your original code and had your code work as intended.

Comment: This is actually my first powershell script that I've been desperately trying to piece together.  Can you please elaborate?  It took everything I had piecing this together lol.

Comment: Do I need to use some sort of gt/ls, if/else logic here with 

  Where-Object { $_.DaysToExpiry -in $dates }

I still think this will try to point expiration to the exact date and time.

Comment: No, `$_.DaysToExpiry` is a number of days until the password expires. Such as, the current date is 1/17/2018, and if their password expired on 1/20/2018 then `$_.DaysToExpiry` would be `3`. `$dates` is now an array of numbers (30, 10, 3, 2, 1). So the statement `Where-Object { $_.DaysToExpiry -in $dates }` effectively checks if the number 3 is in the array 30, 10, 3, 2, 1 (which it is).